# Java search in text file with joptionpane?

Tags: java

Im really new to Java.
So im quite lost here, im working on a project where i should search in a text file for a corresponding word, line by line. I got a little help from someone, but there´s some errors to the GUI in the joptionpane.

This is what i have until now.
My GUI:

```
private void jMenuItemLookupActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Title", "Message", 
    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
    null, options.toArray(new String[] {}), options.get(0));
}
```

And my code for the search.

```
public String lookup(String question){
    List<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object value : data.values()) {
    if (value.toString().startsWith(question)) {
        options.add((String) value);
    }
}
```

Comment: "_there´s some errors to the GUI_" What errors?

Comment: in this line:        null, options.toArray(new String[] {}), options.get(0));
cannot find symbol, variable options

Comment: Did you import `ArrayList`?

Comment: That i have done now, but there´s still the same error. Is there a better way to search in a text file through Joptionpane? Without the options dialog maybe

Answer (score 0):

Move your `List<String> options = new ArrayList<>();` outside the `lookup` method and make it a class variable. Your compiler cannot find options object.